# Create dynamic function name on the fly in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I have an object in which I have a bunch of implicit functions. I now want to have some implicits defined for several date formats: For example.,

```
val dateFormats = Seq("dd/MM/yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

I want to go over this list and generate a function like this:

```
  dateFormats foreach {
    case dateFormat =>
      implicit def ???: CsvFieldReader[DateTime] = (s: String) => Try {
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).parseDateTime(s)
      }
  }
```

How can I resolve the function name? I want the function name to be unique for each entry in the List!

Any ideas? Can I do this with macros?

Comment: How you will use resulting `Seq`?

Comment: I don't want to use them, but just have them as a bunch of implicit defs defined

Comment: It will be useless because compiler will be unable to choose one of them to apply because they all have same signature.

Comment: I see it! I guess I have a workaround! I will post a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create several implicits of the same type `CsvFieldReader[DateTime]` they will make ambiguity and implicits will not resolve.

Names of implicits don't matter ([almost](https://youtu.be/1h8xNBykZqM?t=677)), their types do.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is an implementation that works, even though it looks ugly!

```
implicit def dateTimeCSVConverter: CsvFieldReader[DateTime] = (s: String) => Try {
    dateFormats.map {
      case format => try {
        Some(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format).parseDateTime(s))
      } catch {
        case _: IllegalArgumentException =>
          println(s"Date format $format incompatible, will try the next available format")
          None
      }
    }.distinct.collectFirst {
      case elem if elem.isDefined => elem.get
    }.get
  }
```